# Ensure camera position is always the center of the screen?

Tags: c++, c, math, geometry

Given 2 functions Translate(x,y) and Scale(x), I want the camera's position to always be the center of the screen. There is also a scalefactor variable and by modifying it it either zooms in or out from the center of the screen. Given that I know the dimensions of the screen in pixels, how could I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: That depends on if you really want to scale the image or not. You could always not scale the image, and use the size of the image to just translate it to where it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
screen_coords = (world_coords - camera_world_coords) * camera_zoom + 0.5 * screen_dimension
```

Comment: @Milo: You're not going to get perfectly working code here. SO is not a "Send me code that does X" site. Read the equation tdammers posted and implement it in terms of Translate and Scale.

Comment: Hint: the * operator in my example is a scale, the + and - operators are translates. If you can't figure it out with this information, go back to the grindstone.